# How can I get my 5G wifi to work?

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

I just got a fancy new 5G-enabled dual-band wireless router. My `lspci` says I have a:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

So the 802.11n should be able to see 5G networks, right? Yet I don't see my 5G network in the list of available networks, only the 2.4G version. How can I set up wifi so that I can take full advantage of my new router and wifi card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

802.11n can be both 2.4GHz and 5GHz. I'd guess your card only supports 2.4GHz. The  [product page](http://www.broadcom.com/products/Wireless-LAN/802.11-Wireless-LAN-Solutions/BCM43142) does not mention 5GHz at all. You can see a few chips with 5GHz support on [the product list](http://www.broadcom.com/products/Wireless-LAN/802.11-Wireless-LAN-Solutions), and the support is mentioned explicitly, unlike the case of the BCM43142.